# How to solve this problem of subversion

Tags: tortoise-svn, svn

I have been using TortoiseSVN for a 2-3 months to control my subversion. Today when I tried to commit files to a repository it showed me a strange message like this:

[alt text http://lh4.ggpht.com/_DK4gO8ys6jI/TCoFlCXZ8JI/AAAAAAAABoc/fl9q2aWPjY0/error_msg2.PNG](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_DK4gO8ys6jI/TCoFlCXZ8JI/AAAAAAAABoc/fl9q2aWPjY0/error_msg2.PNG)

When I went to the menu and selected Cleanup command it showed me this new message box:

[alt text http://lh4.ggpht.com/_DK4gO8ys6jI/TCoEws1XFDI/AAAAAAAABoY/osZwXhAXMJA/error_msg.PNG](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_DK4gO8ys6jI/TCoEws1XFDI/AAAAAAAABoY/osZwXhAXMJA/error_msg.PNG)

I have tried to release lock it says that there is nothing to unlock.
What happened with my subversion repository? Has anybody met with this problem before? How to solve it?
A lot of thanks.

Comment: Your repository is probably fine, it's your *working copy* that has problems.

Comment: Broke images. Title doesn't help to understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the working directory (or backup it, if you already did changes). Then, get new a copy from the server (and merge your changes from the backup copy with tool like WinMerge)

Answer (score 1):

Asked and answered on stackoverflow.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127932/svn-working-copy-xxx-locked-and-cleanup-failed